# Tensorflow gradient wrt input

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm experimenting with recent ideas coming from adversarial training and I'm specifically interested in a loss function which includes the input. This means I would like to derive the loss function with respect to the input (not only the model parameters).

One solution I can see is the function tf.conv2d_backprop_input(...). This can work as a solution for conv layers, however I also require a solution for fully connected layers as well. Another way to approach this problem is using the [Cleverhans](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans) library written by Ian Goodfellow and Nicolas Papernot. This can be a more "complete" solution however its usage is not exactly clear (I need a simple example and not a complete API).

I would love to hear your thoughts and methodology on creating a custom deep learning simulation with adverserial training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependence of an output node on the input can be calculated by backpropagation and is called saliency. It can be used to understand which parts of an input are most strongly contributing to a neuron's output for any differentiable neural network. [This repository](https://github.com/PAIR-code/saliency) contains a collection of methods for calculating saliency and links to papers.

Comment: Thanks, this answer really helped (-: